# Install a progressive web application (PWA) on the phone without a network

Tags: deployment, smartphone, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible (e.g. when developing) to send a pwa to the phone someway e..g. via usb cable without the network and serving it in https?

The use case is development, when maybe a wifi network is not available or unpractical to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your APP is fully PWA compliant, the [app added to home will be an installed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514186/1057093), which you can extract using file explorer(I used ES File explorer) and put it in other devices using USB connection and **`adb install myapp.apk`** for installation.

After you load the apk, it would anyways make calls to your web-server which I'm not sure how it make sense to achieve without network connection though. I couldn't think of any reason to develop a mobile application as PWA without network. You can even have a pass though internet(sharing your desktops internet via USB) by connecting via USB if wifi is not available. But developing PWA with absolute no network mode is not practical.

**Update:** While you can generate the APK and side load it via USB in the above mentioned way, transferring the cached assets(HTML/CSS/JS/images) might be tricky. You may have to wrap your app as a plain cordova application or [Ionic kind of PWA app](https://ionicframework.com/pwa) which uses Cordova to wrap and build with your assets. This way, your APK will be having everything it needs to run for calculator kind of use case.

Comment: The app i am developing is calculating tool that needs no network when working, this justifies the use case. Anyway the question *is* properly answered

Comment: That make sense. I'm adding another alternate for your use case. Please check on the update.